# Deep understanding: Why do .bind(this) not seem to follow the normal rules when used with new Promise

Tags: javascript, this, es6-promise

The following code:

```
var this_module = {

    foo: 'something',

    promise: function () {

        return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {

            resolve (this.foo);
        }.bind(this))
    }
}
```

successfully binds `this` to the `this_module`. I cannot understand why.

The `new` operator normally sets `this` to the object created as part of the constructing call to a given function. This should mean that the constructing call to the Promise function would set `this` to the Promise object. If this is the case then `.bind(this)` should also set the executor function's `this` to the Promise object.

Alternatively `.bind(this)` should set the executor function's `this` to the `this` value of the Promise function (which in the above example should be the global object).

Why is this not the case?

Comment: The `new` operator has nothing to do with the function you pass to `Promise`. You are calling `new` on `Promise`, not on the function you pass to `Promise`. *"If this is the case then `.bind(this)` should also set the executor function's `this` to the Promise object."*  The promise object doesn't exist at the moment you call `.bind(this)`. `this` refers to whatever `this` refers to inside `promise: function() {}`. I'm rather confused that you think it should be something else than `this_module`. It follows *exactly* the "normal" rules.

Comment: What you also be confused if you had `var handler = function(resolve, reject) { ... }.bind(this); return new Promise(handler);` instead?

Comment: So how come `this` do not refer to the global object inside the Promise function?

Comment: I assume you mean the callback you pass to `Promise` when you say "Promise function"? What `this` refers to depends on what `this` refers to in `promise: function() { ... }`. If you call the function as `this_module.promise()`, `this` refers to `this_module`. If you do `var p = this_module; p();`, `this` refers to the global object. If you do `this_module.promise.call(foobar)`, `this` refers to `foobar`. These are the "normal" `this` rules, nothing special happening here.

Comment: Well thank you @Felix Kling. I will try and wrap my head around it.

Comment: A side question: Why am I getting down votes on this question .... ?

Comment: FYI, You're missing a comma after 'something', and you're lacking an ending bracket. Always best to review your code before posting.

Comment: When you pass a function definition (callback) to a function it gets assigned to an argument variable of that function. When the passed callback is invoked the `this` in effect is the context of the function taking the callback. In this case normally the Promise object. However since the passed callback is already bound to another context by the bind instruction at it's definition, when invoked it remains bound to it.

Comment: Thank you @Redu. The `.bind` is called at the time of creating the Variable Object (VO) including the Arguments Object (AO). But can you explain me how `this_module.promise()` becomes the call site of `.bind()` (which I assume is necessary for `.bind(this)` to point to `this_module`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var this_module = {

  foo: 'something',

  promise: function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(this.foo);
    }.bind(this));
  }

};
```

Normal rules for `this` apply. The `this` in `bind(this)` occurs within the method `promise` on `this_module`, and thus by definition refers to `this_module` (assuming it is called as `this_module.promise()`). Therefore, the `this` within the function to which it is being applied (in this case the executor--the function being passed as a parameter to `new Promise`), refers to `this_module`, and can access `foo`. Nothing surprising is happening here.

As explained in the comments, the `this` to which the executor is bound, and therefore in effect within the executor, has nothing to do with the promise, or with any `this` referring to the new promise. In fact, you cannot access the promise being constructed, by design. Any `this` referring to the new promise is happening within the `Promise` constructor, which is invisible to you.

Perhaps the downvotes were due to the fact that this code could be explained quite simply by normal rules for `this`, but they do seem a bit harsh.

You might consider that what you wrote is precisely equivalent to the following:

```
var this_module = {

  foo: 'something',

  promise: function () {
    const self = this;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(self.foo);
    });
  }

};
```

and is also equivalent to

```
var this_module = {

  foo: 'something',

  promise: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      resolve(this.foo);
    );
  }

};
```